# How to calculate a minimal necessary production curve?

Tags: graphing-functions, curves, riemann-sum

Say I need to produce 10 billion widgets by the end of the year. But instead of directly producing widgets, I actually produce widget-makers - each of which can produce 10 widgets/min.

What I'd love to be able to do is to calculate the minimum necessary production curve such that I could look at any given point and determine the minimum necessary production rate to likely achieve the goal by the deadline: "As of Aug 1, I am producing 50 widgets/sec and have already produced 15,000,000 widgets. [Run calculation] Ok, so this says that by Aug 30 at 17:00:00, I need to be producing 65 widgets/sec in order to still be on pace to reach 10 billion by end of year." (or whatever the numbers would be)

I've been playing around with some different approaches, but I hit dead ends. I know it's not really a standard exponential growth problem. In fact, I think it's mostly linear. But it's not *simply* linear as there are like 5 variables as I see it.

I've been poking at this some more since I started this post. Here's my progression of thought, starting with a (very) rough equation:

```
a = widgets **a**lready made
Wm = number of **W**idget-**m**akers
p = **p**roduction of widgets/sec/widget-maker (constant)
d = seconds until **d**eadline
t = **t**otal number of widgets needed by deadline (constant)

a + (Wm * p * d) = t
```

Now p and t are constant for any given problem:

```
a + (Wm * 0.17 * d) = 1x10^10
```

But as time progresses, how do I make sure that 'a' gets incremented by the amount of produced widgets since the last second? Let's see if instead of picturing some point in the middle as the starting point, I start at the beginning:

```
0 + (Wm * 0.17 * d) = 1x10^10
```

Then progressing one second forward:

```
(Wm * 0.17 * d) + (Wm * 0.17 * (d-1)) = 1x10^10
```

Then one more second:

```
(Wm * 0.17 * d) + (Wm * 0.17 * (d-1)) + (Wm * 0.17 * (d-2)) = 1x10^10
```

Now it's starting to look like some kind of progressing addition problem. [Is this a Riemann sum? That's literally the last thing I remember doing in math - pre-calc from 20 years ago in HS.]

Anyway, I've been trying to read up on Riemann sums, but not feeling comfortable about anything I'm trying to create from what I'm reading.

Maybe something like:

$$
\sum_{i=d}^{0} (Wm * 0.17 * i) = 1x10^{10}
$$

???

I don't know. I'm far enough outside of familiar math that I don't know if I'm even in the right *continent* at this point. Even if this was somehow (miraculously) the right equation, I'm not sure how to go about solving it - let alone how one would go about graphing something like this. I'm willing to try to figure it out, but I really need some experts to confirm I'm on the right path or to put me on it before I spin my wheels on anything else. So I could use some help. After all, I still don't know what to do with Wm - how does that get incremented over time?

I've tried to do as much legwork myself on this as I could, but I think it's time to call in the big guns to help finish this quest. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Riemann sum, but an arithmetic progression.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{d} (Wm \cdot 0.17 \cdot i) = 0.17\cdot Wm\sum_{i=1}^{d}i=
\boxed{0.17\cdot Wm{d(d+1)\over 2}}
$$
Well, technically, I guess it *is* a Riemann sum, now that I think of it, but since you're not taking the limit as the mesh of the partition goes to $0,$ it's not a useful concept here.

Comment: Thank you for responding. So I actually got close to the needed equation for the problem?! I honestly felt I was grasping at straws there. Anyway, so for the final step, if I wanted to graph this with time along the x-axis and ensure I reach the total goal that needs to be produced, would that looks something like:

0.17y * ((x(x+1))/2) = 10^10

That seems like a [strange graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8wzbu2lsuz)

Comment: Well it doesn't make sense if $x\leq0$  Remember that $x$ represents days.  It also doesn't make sense to look at values of $x$ larger than the number of days to the date of contract completion.  I suppose you've simplified the problem to present it as  a question, but if I were doing this, I'd certainly plan to stop making widget makers some time before the end of the year, to allow for breakdowns.  It seems like you should plan to have enough widgets makers on line to fulfill the contract by the end of October or whatever, so you have some wiggle room.

Comment: Right, and I had no problem ignoring anything to the left of the y-axis. But the graph to the right of that I would expect to be mostly linear - a slowly increasing rate of production. And even if I viewed this as a backwards growth rate (starting with x = large number of seconds, moving toward 0 seconds left until deadline), it still looks exponential - even if I change the total to something reasonable like 10^3.

Comment: And of course I'd set the deadline short of the *actual* deadline and would plan for breakdowns and whatnot if this were for a physical application - but it's just for a simulation (a game to be frank), so no breakdowns or failures or power issues or worker strikes. Just a raw theoretical production rate problem.

Comment: @user29021  Ah, I wondered about 10 billion widgets.

Comment: @user29021 No, the graph is the reciprocal of quadratic.  If you can somehow reduce the range of $x$ to something reasonable like $100<x<300$ then I think the graph will make more sense to you.